Distribution of the random variable $\mathbb{P}(Y|X)$
Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A})\rightarrow(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$ be random variables. Consider the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(Y|X):\Omega\times\mathcal{G}\rightarrow [0,1]$, which is a markov kernel from $(\Omega, \sigma(X))$ into $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$.
Then, this conditional distribution is a random variable from $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$ for each $G\in\mathcal{G}$. But what is the distribution of this random variable? Is it simply $\mathbb{P}$?
And as a closely related question: If $f:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function (in the same setting as above), what is the distribution of the random variable $f(X)$? Is it $\mathbb{P}_X$?

The Markov Kernel is defined on $\Omega \times \mathcal G, $ isn't it?

you are right, i updated it thank you

@User1865345 can you answer my questions, or give a hint?

Consider them as  ordinary random variables for a fixed $B.$ Like denote them as a measurable function $g_B(\omega) $ on $(\Omega, \mathcal A). $ What is the distribution then?

More precisely, they don't need separate treatment just because they are kernels for when you consider them as random map, you are fixing the other entity it depends on.

So lets say we define $g_B(\omega) = \mathbb{P}(Y\in B|X)(\omega)$, then $g_B:\Omega\rightarrow [0,1]$. So the distribution would be the pushforwar measure $\mathbb{P}_{g_B}(A) =\mathbb{P}({g_B \in A})$ with $A\in\mathcal{B}([0,1])$, the Borel sigma algebra on [0,1]?

is this correct?

That seemed to be correct.
